# Symlink a folder

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to simlink an entire folder:

```
link "/path-to-destination/" do
  provider Chef::Provider::Link
  action :create
  to "/path-to-original/"
  link_type :symbolic
end
```

> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory

I then tried to first create the folder, then sun the simlink, but then I get an error saying directory already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean `link "/path-to-destination"`. Adding that extra `/` changes the meaning.